# Mingw and _stati64()

Tags: c, mingw

I am using `_stati64()` in my file manager so that I can get the size of files over 4gb.

My code looks normal:

```
struct _stati64 buf;
_stati64(ep->d_name, &buf);
```

The thing is, sometimes `_stati64` works properly, sometimes I get huge values. I even checked with gdb, by doing `print buf` and still get bad values, so the problem doesn't seem to be with my code.
Did anyone experience something similar?

Comment: Show all the code. (and check that your _stati64() doesn't fail)

Comment: You get bad values *for* *what*? Which values are bad and what are the actual values you get?

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem, just after posting (and I spent 1 hours looking for it). The problem was my code, not the _stati64 function, I copied it from another part of the code and passed the wrong path :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the return value of `_stati64`. If it's not 0, you won't have valid results.

If your actual code does check the return value, the error is most likely that you are somehow corrupting the structure after `_stati64` returns.

The last possibility is that the "bad values" you get are actually valid and good values. I'll update my answer if you update the question with what values you are getting.

Comment: Yes, that was it, I didn't bother to check for errors because I just replaced a normal stat(), with the _stati64, and while doing so I used the wrong variable for the path :/ It's really frustrating when you find the answer to the problem right after you post, even though you can spend an hour before trying to figure out what's wrong :)